# FullCalendar initialView not updating correctly on screen resize in React

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I'm working on a React project that utilizes FullCalendar, and I'm encountering an issue with the initialView property not updating correctly when the screen is resized. Here's a simplified version of the relevant code:

```
// Relevant imports and setup...

export default function Calendar({
  teamSlug,
  calendarId,
}: {
  teamSlug: string;
  calendarId: string;
}) {
  const [data, setData] = useState<{ [key: string]: ProductUserDTO } | undefined>(undefined);
  const [productSlugUser, setProductSlugUser] = useLocalStorageTX2<string | undefined>('productSlugUser', undefined);
  const [startPaymentReqs, setStartPaymentReqs] = useLocalStorageTX2<{
    [programId: string]: Partial<StartPaymentReq>;
  }>('startPaymentReqs', {});
  const auth = useAuth();

  const [initialView, setInitialView] = useState('timeGridWeek');

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch data...

  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleResize = () => {
      const newInitialView = window.innerWidth < 600 ? 'timeGridDay' : 'timeGridWeek';
      setInitialView(newInitialView);
    };

    // Set initial view on component mount
    handleResize();

    // Attach event listener for window resize
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    // Remove event listener on component unmount
    return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
  }, []);

  let eventInputs = convertProductsToEventInputs(data, productSlugUser);

  // ... other code

  return (
    <div>
      {/* ... */}
      <FullCalendar
        key={initialView} // Force remounting when initialView changes
        plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, listPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
        initialView={initialView}
        // ... other props
      />
      {/* ... */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? As I understand it, `initialView` just sets the view that the calendar starts on (the clue is in the name of the property, after all!). So fullCalendar only takes notice of it when the calendar is first initialised. If you want to change the view later on due to some event in the browser, then you would need to call the [changeView](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-changeView) function, I expect